# Unknown property generateLombokConfig.enabled after ugrading gradle from 6.9 to 7.3

Tags: gradle, lombok, gradlew

I have a property called `generateLombokConfig.false` in the code which I received.

The code was built for java 8. Now am upgrading it for Java 17. When I upgrade to Java 16 compatible version of Gradle (7.3) , Lombok (6.3), the code fails to build with error

```
Could not get unknown property 'generateLombokConfig' for root project 'myapp' of type org.gradle.api.Project
```

Is this property deprecated? Is it safe to remove ? I dont find any information in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is deprecated and removed from the latest Lombok version. No helpful documentation apart from [this](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/6.5.1/api/io/freefair/gradle/plugins/lombok/tasks/GenerateLombokConfig.html) javadoc

Answer (score 0):

It was removed because the feature was removed entirely. You are now expected to manually create the lombok config file.

Have a look at https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/379

Comment: There is already an accepted answer.